# References comparing the two different definitions of joule expansion coefficient

Tags: thermodynamics

Some pieces of literature derives Joule thompson coefficent using enthalpy $H$ and others derive it using internal energy $U$ ... so which one is the right one? If they are both equivalent, then how do you prove their equivalence?

Edit: Ok, I realized there are actually two different JT coefficents called the JT coefficent. So,  I seek an answer which discusses both.

---

**Sources which derive using internal energy:**

[Lecture -3 of mit ocw  around 49:14](https://youtu.be/RrVq7Yduz2g?t=2956)

[Page-63 of Atkin's physical chemistry (internal edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198769865)

[Robert G. Mortimer - Physical Chemistry (page -63) for experimental explanation of this phenomena](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005H89KGK)

**Sources which derive using enthalpy:**

[Joule thompson coefficent in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)

[Charles Kittel, Herbert Kroemer - Thermal physics-W. H. Freeman](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0716710889) [ page 362, chapter-12 cryogenics]

[In chemistry libre text](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Physical_Chemistry_(Fleming)/04%3A_Putting_the_First_Law_to_Work/4.05%3A_The_Joule-Thomson_Effect)

Comment: There are actually two different JT coefficients, referring to two different experiments.  The one involving constant H refers to an experiment in which the gas is flowed through a resistance from a higher pressure to a slightly lower pressure.  The one involving constant U refers to an experiment in which a gas in a closed insulated container is separated by a partition with the gas in a larger section and vacuum in the other tiny section.  The partition is suddenly removed and the gas is allowed to equilibrate.  The two values are the same only for an ideal gas.

Comment: Oh... can you give references for each experiment? edit: on second thought I guess I might have been missing that point in the texts. I'll read it each agian.

Comment: Your references describe the two experiments.

Comment: This post (v3) does not look like a valid use of the res. recom. tag or the spec. ref. tag, cf. their tag wikis. Note that they have a restricted use on Phys.SE, cf. various meta discussions.

Comment: Why? and how would I fix it? basically I am using for references which contrasts the difference between the two derivatoins

Comment: Why are you asking for references when it is easy enough to derive the relationships yourself?

Comment: I want an authoritative reference in case for when I can do a detailed study later